# Manipulating string data in R to specific format

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a large chunk of text:

```
test<-"ABC (0033 - test), CCPM (0431 - CCPM), FGC (0432 -YYY)"
```

I want to manipulate them such that it becomes:

```
 ABC (0033 - test),0033       
 CCPM (0431 - CCPM),0431
 FGC (0432 -YYY),0432
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so share your code and describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("(\\d+)([^)]+\\))", "\\1\\2,\\1", test)
[1] "ABC (0033 - test),0033, CCPM (0431 - CCPM),0431, FGC (0432 -YYY),0432"
```

If we need to print

```
cat(gsub("(\\d+)([^)]+\\)),*", "\\1\\2,\\1\n", test), sep="\n")
# ABC (0033 - test),0033
# CCPM (0431 - CCPM),0431
# FGC (0432 -YYY),0432
```

---

If we need to have a vector with 3 separate elements

```
unname(sapply(strsplit(test, ", ")[[1]], function(x) 
    paste(x, regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+", x)), sep=",")))
#[1] "ABC (0033 - test),0033"  "CCPM (0431 - CCPM),0431" "FGC (0432 -YYY),0432"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Why is it that sometimes I get a comma at the beginning of each row, when I print the results?

Comment: @Headandtoes  I am not getting any comma at the beginning of row if you check the second output